# IntelliJ doesn't seem to pickup certain sbt libraries, no code completion

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I am using sbt console in my terminal to compile my scala/play project.

I am using intellij to edit my source code, basically using it just for getting some code completion and navigation etc.

For some reason certain libraries don't seem to load correctly.  For example, I added elastic search to my Dependancies.scala file, reloaded sbt and everything compiles fine but for some reason IntelliJ doesn't pickup the jars correctly i.e. they are in red and there is no syntax completion.

How can I fix this?  I tried shutting intellij down and restarting it but the problem remains.

I am using Intelli 13.1.3 (ultimate)

[image]

Comment: Please give your SBT version as well as the content of built.sbt (or wherever you put your dependencies). Do you use the SBT plugin ?

Comment: did you perform `play idea` command after adding new dependencies???

Comment: @biesior I ran it again and it restarted idea, still no change.

Comment: @Blankman I'm having exact same issue right now with my project. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you use IDEA 13.x with the Scala plugin, you can directly import your SBT file (File -> Import Project...), and you don't need the sbt-idea plugin. If during the Import you select "Use auto-import", it will automatically sync any changes to your build.sbt file.

At one time I had the problem of IDEA getting confused and not autocompleting / labelling dependencies as errors. In that case, using File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... fixed the problem. That hasn't happened to me in recent versions, though.

Comment: I tried this before and it literally took over 30 minutes to import..not trying that again.

Comment: Thanks for this. gen-idea is now outdated for idea 14.x. @Blankman , you can dig through your ivy cache at ~/.ivy2 and try deleting only the offending groups. Nuking dependency caches is always painful, especially when you have a lot of dependencies and/or a slow connection. It can easily get to 500MB.

Comment: One more note, import the project by selecting the build.sbt file, NOT the project dir, or it won't infer that it's an sbt project.

Answer (score 1):

When adding dependencies in general is good practice to regenerate idea xml configuration files (inside .idea and/or .idea_modules and the correlated .iml files), try adding [this plugin](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) and then use `sbt gen-idea`, or even better if you're using play you can simply use `sbt idea with-sources=yes` which ships with play as shown [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/IDE).

Idea utilizes xml to store configurations, in fact if you look at them right now probably you won't find the jars/library you just added, simply because they are not automatically updated.

Comment: Yes I am using that plugin already.  Do I have to re-generated it you mean after I updated my sbt project?

Comment: When adding a new dependency Intellij can't see it because it's looking at the xml configuration files which have not been updated, if you search inside your `.idea` folder it should contain all your dependencies. For example I added the `google ads` dependency in my project and in various places in my `.idea` folder I have reference to that dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue when bringing in a project from Github via IntelliJ's "Checkout from version control". When importing, I was given 2 options - 'import from external sources' or pick a project type (Maven, SBT, etc.) and had chosen the former.

I think I should have chosen to import from SBT. But with the route I did, it was giving me OP's problem. To fix, once I loaded the Scala SDK into the project, it asked if I wanted to import the SBT project. I did this, then I went to the build.sbt file and did a refresh project (not sure if this step is needed or not). However, then I saw in the modules, that it had used a `main` as a modules root. So I went into module settings, and removed the `main` as a module, and just left the root folder (usually with the project name) as the only module. This should do it - do another refresh project in your SBT to bring in the project-build module, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly "File > Invalidate Caches..." and the other proposed solutions did not help.

For me a solution was to ditch the configuration and start IntelliJ with fresh (default) settings. Maybe some quirks occurred there.

On macOS I've removed this folder(s):

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea*
```